# uipickerview index out if range

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uipickerviewdatasource

I'm trying to learn to code Swift and recently I faced a bug which is so embarrassing. 
I have 2 textfield which both are connected to a picker view.

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        if EntCity.isEditing
        {
            return MainCities[row].name
        }

        return MainJ[row].name
        }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if EntState.isFirstResponder
        {
            EntState.text = MainJ[row].name
            Global_Addresses.global_address.cityID_fromState = MainJ[row].id
            GetCities()
        }
        if EntCity.isEditing
        {
            if (EntState.text?.isEmpty)!
            {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.DisplayMessage(UserMessage: "ابتدا استان را انتخاب کنید")
                }

            }
            else
            {
            EntCity.text = MainCities[row].name
            Global_Addresses.global_address.smallCityID = MainCities[row].id
            }
        }

        EntState.text = MainJ[row].name
        Global_Addresses.global_address.cityID_fromState = MainJ[row].id
        GetCities()

        func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return  1
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

            return  MainCities.count
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

            return MainCities[row].name
        }

        func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

            EntCity.text = MainCities[row].name
            Global_Addresses.global_address.smallCityID = MainCities[row].id
            print("?????????????????????")
            print(Global_Addresses.global_address.smallCityID)

        }
}
```

the code works fine and both textfield can show the data in the picker view to choose. these textfield are connected, it means that 
you have to choose one of the rows in textfield number 1 to get the data for textfield number 2 . when i choose the first data , and select the second textfield to choose the second one , it works fine untill i choose of those data which their row number is bigger than the first textfield 
and as you can see i have declared that if it select first or second textfield to return different number for row!

Comment: why are you using didselectrow two times?

Comment: don't use didselect row method of picker view because its called when you change picker but what if user just open and select first value in picker at that time didselect row method of picker is not called `let row = picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)` you can use this.this will return an index of selected row and why you have added titleforrow and didselect methos twice you can't do that

Comment: @RahulGUsai I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: what part you dont understand?

Comment: when a user selects a specific row it will send some data to a global class and I save them there and I use them later in my URLs or maybe I show them.